# How to disable support for iDevices

Tags: usb, iphone

Googling for Ubuntu and iPhone leads to many posts about getting them to work together. I have given up on that part. I have a USB lead on my desk which I use solely for charging my devices. Every time I charge my iPhone, Ubuntu gives me the "Unhandle lockdown error" message.

My question is simple, how can I completely remove the detection of my phone? I don't want to mount it, browse it or even see an icon in the dock for it. When I charge my phone I'd prefer Ubuntu to not recognize it rather than give me useless popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and I don't have Apple devices to check but I'd say disabling related udev rules should work. Comment out all lines in `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-libgpod.rules` and this line:

```
ATTRS{vendor}=="*Apple*", ATTRS{model}=="*iPod*", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="apple_ipod"
```

in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules`.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it didn't work. I still get the "Unable to mount iPhone" error.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I will remove the answer later.